# Definition of a framework

Tags: .net, definition

What is the exact definition of a framework ? What does it mean when people say that .NET is a framework . Is it something like a programming language ? What are the things that the concept of framework envelopes as compared to the ambit of the term "programming language " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In general, a framework is a real or conceptual structure intended to serve as a support or guide for the building of something that expands the structure into something useful.

basiclly it means, that a framework is like a Hub that knows to get content (in some proggraming languege foe example), and interperate it.
You can put it right on the sweet spot between a protocol and a structure.

Comment: idik : Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Not much to elaborate about... its just a set of rules, that are being used to  decide with what proggraming langueges, databases, protocols, etc. a certein enviroment will be able to co-oparate and handle.

Comment: Sure... a lot of tutorials in youtube and other sites. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBmyIaDz0_Y&list=PLr6-GrHUlVf_EBZ5NShNqhLjhRk3muGlY this is pretty good to start with.

Also, an upvote for my answer will be appriciated :)